# Unable to start Topshelf service with command line parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services, topshelf, servicehost

I am using topshelf along with .net core and registering it with command line parameter something like below.

```
x.AddCommandLineDefinition("mode", f => { mode = f; });
x.ApplyCommandLine();
```

The below commands for installing service works perfectly but it gives exception while starting the service

```
sample.exe install -mode:normal
```

This executes and installs the service without exception. However,

```
sample.exe start -mode:normal
```

throws this generic exception.**The service did not respond to
the start or control request in a timely fashion
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
   at Topshelf.Runtime.Windows.WindowsHostEnvironment.StartService(String servic
eName, TimeSpan startTimeOut)
   at Topshelf.Hosts.StartHost.Run()**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Start() to just start the service, and returning from it quickly?

Comment: I might have been a little vague there, so what I meant is if you followed the [quick start](https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html), I’m referring to your equivalent of the TownCrier.Start() method.